# My haskell type signature does not represent the function

Tags: haskell

The following code runs but I am not sure why the type signature requires a float to be inupt.

```
farenheitToCelcius :: Float -> Float
farenheitToCelcius farenheit = (5/9)*(farenheit-32)

main :: IO()
main = print (show (farenheitToCelcius 67))
```

The type signature to the following:

```
farenheitToCelcius :: Int-> Float
farenheitToCelcius farenheit = (5/9)*(farenheit-32)

main :: IO()
main = print (show (farenheitToCelcius 67))
```

Results in this error?:

```
main.hs:2:32: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: (5 / 9) * (farenheit - 32)
      In an equation for ‘farenheitToCelcius’:
          farenheitToCelcius farenheit = (5 / 9) * (farenheit - 32)
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I am using repl.it.

Comment: I can not reproduce it. The only problem I can see here is that you defined it as `Float -> Float`, but later in your question, you specify it as `Int -> Float`.

Comment: English is not my first language so sorry if I'm not clear. `farenheitToCelcius :: Float -> Float` results in working code but `replacing it with `farenheitToCelcius :: Int -> Float` does not. I don't however understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume that the division `5/9` is using the fractional division, which is not defined for `Int`.

Comment: Even if this wasn't a type error... it basically never makes sense to represent a physical quantity like temperature by an integer, why do you want that?

Comment: @leftaroundabout It makes perfect sense to represent physical quantities by integers. Lots of sensors (maybe even most) work that way. The way it's used in this particular instance (just ignoring fractional parts) isn't a good way to handle this, but I'm guessing OP just wanted to know why this is a type error.

Comment: @Cubic no it doesn't make sense. Those sensors actually work with _fixed-precision real numbers_, i.e. floats with a fixed exponent, as it were. Yes, low-level languages may simply use an integer for this, but that's really unsafe – if you do any kind of computation, in particular involving sensors with different precision, you get utter garbage results. Quantifying everything to integer of some single conventional unit needlessly reduces the precision further. Floating-point largely avoids those problems, though one should still use wrappers to avoid unit mismatches. (Mars Climate Orbiter...)

Comment: I'm guessing @Cubic may have meant it in the sense that floating point numbers are countable and finite, even though in the real world everyone treats them as a representation of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the numerical operations like `*`, `+` and `/` are defined for operations on the same number type only - i.e, if you have `x + y` then both `x` and `y` need to have the same type, and the result will be of the same type again. You can convert an integer-like type to any other number type using the `fromIntegral` function though, so if you want your function to be of type `Int -> Float` you simply need to add it here:

```
farenheitToCelcius :: Int-> Float
farenheitToCelcius farenheit = (5/9)*(fromIntegral farenheit-32)
```

Note also that the `/` operator is *not* defined for integers (for integer division you need to use the `div` function instead), so if you wanted this to be a function of type `Int -> Int` there'd be some other things you'd need to do here.

Comment: Why is `5/9` not giving an error along the lines of "not defined for int"? I think your answer would benefit if you explain why the error is "Couldn't match expected ..." instead of "No Instance For (Fractional Int) ...".

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Because `5` and `9` are not integers; They're literals of type `Num a => a`, `5/9` then becomes `Fractional a => a` without further restrictions, and since the whole expression is restricted to `Float` already because of the type signature the type checker has no problem restricting this to `Float`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann `/` in Haskell is a sort of overloaded operator which can work on float, double, complex, user-defined numeric types. It does not expect any specific type, but only requires that the two arguments have the same type `a`, and that `a` is of class `Fractional` (where `/` is defined). Haskell has no notion of "promotion" in numeric types, and all the conversions much be done explicitly (this is both a curse and a bliss). Numeric literals like `5` have no fixed type, but are polymorphic and will adapt to any type the context requires (`5+x` will make `5` to have the type of `x`)